# Android libGDX error on launch No JNI_Onload found

Tags: android, android-ndk, intellij-idea, libgdx

My game runs on the Desktop, but when I launch on Android I can see these messages appearing in the log.

```
04-01 21:50:10.314: D/ActivityThread(21047): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
04-01 21:50:10.334: D/dalvikvm(21047): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.vulcanic.flickit/lib/libgdx.so 0x41e53a48
04-01 21:50:10.334: D/dalvikvm(21047): Added shared lib /data/data/com.vulcanic.flickit/lib/libgdx.so 0x41e53a48
04-01 21:50:10.334: D/dalvikvm(21047): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.vulcanic.flickit/lib/libgdx.so 0x41e53a48, skipping init
04-01 21:50:10.344: D/libEGL(21047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
04-01 21:50:10.344: D/libEGL(21047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
04-01 21:50:10.354: D/libEGL(21047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB4.04.01.02.16.049_msm8960_JB_REL_RB4.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): Build Date: 12/12/12 Wed
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): Local Branch: 
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb4.2
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): Local Patches: NONE
04-01 21:50:10.364: I/Adreno200-EGL(21047): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB4.04.01.02.16.049 +  NOTHING
```

I have the `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` directories within the libs directory on the Android project.

If it helps, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an error. `JNI_OnLoad` is not required in NDK libraries. Just ignore.